# Matrix Chernoff sampling with out replacement

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, it.information-theory, measure-concentration

I am interested to know if the matrix Chernoff bound (see Theorem 5.1.1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.01571.pdf) holds if one samples without replacement.

For example, the Bernstein inequality is argued to hold if one samples without replacement (https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.2738).